# Iterating thru specific table record values to use for filtering a query from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

There's a temp table named **`Tbl`** that's created from a query (*likely  irrelevant to know tho*) that runs for any specific day but typically just the current date (`CURDATE()`) where ***there will always and only be two `BatNum` (Batch Number) records*** where the oldest `TimeStr` will be the start time and the newest `TimeStr` will be the end time for each `BatNum`.

These are the records we start with so there is no problem here but this is what we base everything we get from the other table. While there are three different sets of `BatNum` records (1,2,3) in this small example I provided, there could be just 1 or there could be up to 30.

> ### Tbl Table
>
> [image]
>
> ---
>
> ### Tbl Explained
>
> [image]

---

### [My SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ec7f9/3)

I create an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ec7f9/3) here with a small sample of the data from the `Weight` table and I put a kind of larger sample size of that data in the **Raw SQL** section too just in case.

These are just scaled down samples of the data from the `Weights` table in a specific range records wise but it could be 50,000, 25,000, etc. for a given batch (i.e. per each `BatNum` group).

---

### My Question

*I'm putting this logic into a stored procedure if that even matters any with **MySQL**.*

- I'm trying to somehow from the `Tbl` table for each of the two `TimeStr` value records per each of the `BatNum` grouping (always two), use those to get the records from the `Weight` table and then aggregate that data (per grouping) with various functions, etc. for whatever records are needed.

---

**My Ideas (uh oh... spaghettios)**

I wasn't sure if I could dynamically create a `@StartTime` and an `@EndTime` variable and have their values be iterated from each of the `BatNum` group `TimeStr` values and then use in another query, etc. with MySQL.

- For example I could run a query with this type of filtering (**`WHERE TimeStr BETWEEN @StartTime AND @EndTime`**) and for each number of `BatNum` groups (*e.g. three*) with the `@StartTime` and `@EndTime` values in each query being set as the `TimeStr` value per each `BatNum` group—but I could use `MIN(TimeStr)`, `MAX(TimeStr)`, or maybe `ORDER BY TimeStr [ASC/DESC] LIMIT 1` to know which is start and which is end to set accordingly.

To give you an idea, an example of what the values iterated per each `BatNum` group from `Tbl` would be:

> **From BatNum = 1 Records** (iteration 1)
>
> - `SET @StartTime = '2017-12-14 06:12:31';`
> - `SET @EndTime   = '2017-12-14 07:45:55';`
> - `SET @val       = 15;`
>
> **From BatNum = 2 Records** (iteration 2)
>
> - `SET @StartTime = '2017-12-14 07:45:56';`
> - `SET @EndTime   = '2017-12-14 12:15:51';`
> - `SET @val       = 12;`
>
> **From BatNum = 3 Records** (iteration 3)
>
> - `SET @StartTime = '2017-12-14 12:15:52';`
> - `SET @EndTime   = '2017-12-14 16:20:58';`
> - `SET @val       = 15;`

In the end for example I may need to use something like:

```
SELECT  @Val            oz
        , COUNT(Value)  count
        , AVG(Value)    average
        , STDDEV(Value) stddev
FROM Weights 
WHERE TimeStr BETWEEN @StartTime AND @EndTime;
```

I'm just not sure how to best handle iterating through the records of each `BatNum` group from the `Tbl` table so I figured I'd ask for some help.

---

**Don't forget about:**

- [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ec7f9/3)

---

### Raw SQL

```
CREATE TABLE `Tbl` (
  `BatNum` int NOT NULL,
  `TimeStr` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Value` float NOT NULL,
  KEY `idx_TimeStr` (`TimeStr`)
);

INSERT INTO `Tbl` (`BatNum`,`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES (1,'2017-12-14 06:12:31',15);
INSERT INTO `Tbl` (`BatNum`,`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES (1,'2017-12-14 07:45:55',15);
INSERT INTO `Tbl` (`BatNum`,`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES (2,'2017-12-14 07:45:56',12);
INSERT INTO `Tbl` (`BatNum`,`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES (2,'2017-12-14 12:15:51',12);
INSERT INTO `Tbl` (`BatNum`,`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES (3,'2017-12-14 12:15:52',15);
INSERT INTO `Tbl` (`BatNum`,`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES (3,'2017-12-14 16:20:58',15);

CREATE TABLE `Weights` (
  `TimeStr` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Value` float NOT NULL,
  KEY `idx_TimeStr` (`TimeStr`)
);

INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:12:31',431);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:12:44',431.2);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:12:51',430.7);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:12:59',431.2);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:13:08',430.9);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:13:14',431.3);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:13:20',431.1);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:13:26',431);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:13:40',431.2);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:13:47',430.7);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:17:58',442);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:17:59',461.6);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:17:59',367.1);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:18:00',361.6);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:18:00',381);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:18:01',382.5);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:18:01',380.3);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:18:02',370);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:18:03',432.3);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:18:03',466.6);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:18:04',397.8);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:18:04',439.9);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:18:04',459.3);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:18:05',430.8);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:18:05',385.8);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:18:06',380);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:18:06',386.5);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:18:07',395.3);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:18:07',405.2);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:18:08',387.8);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:18:08',379.4);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:18:09',373.7);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:18:09',372.1);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:18:09',368.3);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:18:10',374.8);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:18:10',386.9);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:18:11',403.2);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:18:11',405.2);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:18:12',409.1);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:18:13',403.6);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:18:13',389);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:18:14',423.8);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:18:14',412.9);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:18:15',407.9);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:18:15',386.5);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:18:16',421);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:18:16',367.2);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:18:16',375.5);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:18:17',373.6);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 06:18:17',376);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:49',377.2);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:49',443);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:48',439.9);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:47',439.6);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:46',0);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:46',453.9);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:45',453);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:45',447.5);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:44',465.5);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:44',457.9);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:43',436.6);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:43',440.8);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:42',447.1);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:42',439);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:41',438.9);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:41',438);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:40',432);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:40',433.9);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:40',443.9);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:39',457);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:39',444.1);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:38',457.5);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:38',463.6);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:37',441.2);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:37',435);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:36',445.8);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:36',433.9);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:35',435.9);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:35',438.6);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:34',433);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:34',431.2);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:33',436.2);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:33',453.3);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:33',451.1);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:32',454.6);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:32',466.8);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:31',433.5);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:30',448.8);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:30',446);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:29',438.8);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:29',439.9);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:28',443.2);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:28',435.7);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:27',443.1);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:27',453);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:27',457.1);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:26',456.3);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:26',462.4);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:25',469.9);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:44:25',444.3);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:49:13',352.8);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:49:19',352.4);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:49:26',352.7);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:49:33',352.5);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:49:40',352.8);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:49:47',352.5);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:49:53',352.7);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:50:00',352.5);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:50:06',352.7);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:50:13',352.6);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:58:11',358.7);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:58:11',0);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:58:16',377.2);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:58:16',0);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:58:18',375.9);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:58:19',376.4);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:58:19',377.7);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:58:19',377.3);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:58:20',380.6);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:58:20',381.7);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:58:21',380.5);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:58:22',376);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:58:22',376.4);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:58:22',377.3);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:58:23',378.3);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:58:23',381.3);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:58:24',380.1);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:58:24',378);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:58:25',380.4);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:58:26',385.4);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:58:26',387.6);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:58:26',389.8);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:58:27',399.9);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:58:27',406.6);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:58:27',0);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:58:29',394.7);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:58:29',395.4);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:58:30',407.1);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:58:30',417.8);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:58:30',433.6);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:58:31',418.8);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:58:31',0);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:58:33',426.2);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:58:33',448);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:58:34',453);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:58:34',450.1);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:58:34',435.9);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:58:35',432.6);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:58:35',441.2);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 07:58:36',460.8);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:22',381.8);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:21',379);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:21',378.4);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:20',373);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:19',0);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:18',377.3);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:18',375.2);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:18',374.5);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:17',375);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:17',380);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:16',382.3);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:16',378.6);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:15',380.9);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:15',377.3);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:15',374.6);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:14',377.5);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:14',380);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:13',383);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:13',381);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:13',374.6);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:12',375.6);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:12',376.7);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:11',383.2);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:11',385);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:10',379.2);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:10',384.7);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:09',390.6);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:09',380.6);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:09',375.5);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:08',376.5);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:08',379.1);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:07',379.3);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:07',378.3);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:06',376.7);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:06',376.5);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:06',374.6);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:05',380.8);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:05',382.6);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:04',383);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:04',380.6);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:03',376);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:03',372.7);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:03',376.9);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:02',383.3);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:02',381.3);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:01',379.7);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:01',377.2);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:00',374);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:15:00',378);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:14:59',379);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:19:03',427.3);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:19:09',427.1);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:19:15',427);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:19:21',427.4);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:19:27',427.5);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:19:33',427.2);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:19:39',427);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:19:46',427.5);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:19:59',427.4);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:23:01',425.3);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:23:02',434);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:23:02',418.2);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:23:03',429.6);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:23:03',479.4);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:23:04',454.3);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:23:04',415.2);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:23:04',416.2);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:23:05',396.1);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:23:05',400.8);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:23:06',395.7);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:23:06',410.8);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:23:07',440);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:23:07',426.2);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:23:08',471);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:23:08',384.4);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:23:09',469.9);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:23:09',433.8);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:23:09',440.9);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:23:10',472.2);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:23:11',425.9);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:23:11',473.3);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:23:12',386);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:23:12',384.7);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:23:13',443.5);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:23:13',434.1);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:23:13',457.8);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:23:14',417.9);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:23:14',422.1);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:23:15',464.1);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:23:16',475);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:23:16',427);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:23:17',445);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:23:18',456.4);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:23:18',459.4);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:23:19',441.7);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:23:19',483.2);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:23:20',411);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:23:20',489.9);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:23:21',453.8);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 12:23:21',474);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:20:58',426.4);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:20:57',446.5);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:20:57',396.2);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:20:57',483.3);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:20:56',419.9);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:20:56',427.5);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:20:55',407.5);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:20:55',402);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:20:54',435.4);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:20:54',406.9);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:20:53',421);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:20:53',437.8);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:20:53',432.2);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:20:52',400.2);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:20:52',426.5);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:20:51',472.3);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:20:51',419.4);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:20:50',447.6);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:20:50',420.8);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:20:50',428.9);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:20:49',463.5);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:20:49',453.7);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:20:42',457.3);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:20:42',461.1);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:20:41',461.3);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:20:40',456.6);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:14:47',455.6);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:14:44',453.6);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:14:43',456.7);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:14:42',457.2);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:14:42',450.8);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:14:41',446.4);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:14:41',443.7);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:14:40',448.6);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:14:40',445.7);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:14:39',441.8);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:14:39',439.3);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:14:38',435.2);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:14:38',433.2);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:14:37',433.5);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:14:37',434.6);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:14:36',430.7);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:14:36',425.6);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:14:36',425.4);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:14:35',426);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:14:35',422);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:14:34',421.2);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:14:34',420.9);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:14:33',420.2);
INSERT INTO `Weights` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2017-12-14 16:14:33',422.4);
```

Comment: I am not very sure how did you create the @ startTime and @ endTime variable. Can you edit the example to explain these values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you need a Stored Procedure, but you need one (or more) views or temporary tables  that have the Batch Number and Weight (oz) associated with the Weights in the weight table. Once you have that, you can create any sort of aggregated value from that view.

Here in the following is the query that will give you the temp table.

```
SELECT p.`Value`, q.BatNum, q.Value oz
FROM `weights` p
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT a.BatNum BatNum, a.TimeStr sTime, b.TimeStr eTime, a.value Value
   FROM Tbl a
   LEFT JOIN Tbl b ON (a.BatNum = b.BatNum)
   WHERE a.TimeStr < b.TimeStr) q 
  ON (p.`TimeStr` BETWEEN q.sTime and q.eTime)
```

This should give you an output like the following:

```
Value     BatNum    oz
431       1         15
431.2     1         15
...  
....
352.8     2         12
352.4     2         12
......
.....
427.3     3         15
427.1     3         15
.....
.....
```

From this above table or view you can create the final query such as

```
SELECT oz, count(value), avg(value)
FROM createdView
GROUP BY BatNum
```

If you are using mysql, creation of the view need little more effort than directly copying the query from here. You may also need to optimize the query in the case of generating faster result from large data.

Comment: With this solution and a few minor tweaks with the real data I was working with, I was able to get the desired results. It would be very helpful if MySQL supported joining a temp table to itself though but I overcame the limitation with workarounds. I appreciate your time sir, I definitely learned some things from this too!!